# "self.fields['field_name'].queryset" in Djano, can it be applied to a OneToOne field?

Tags: django, set, django-queryset

I'm new to Django and have been trying to wrap my head around OneToOne field relationship with _set.all()

My models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_employee = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_manager = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_assistant = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Profile(models.Model):
    profile = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Manager(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_profile = models.OneToOneField(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I'm trying to update a Manager instance and not quite sure why `self.instance.user.profile_set.all()` keeps throwing an "'User' object has no attribute 'profile_set'" AttributeError in this section:

forms.py

```
elif self.instance.pk:
        self.fields['user_profile'].queryset = self.instance.user.profile_set.all()
```

I hope my question is clear, any help would be greatly appreciated!
Cheers!

Comment: It's `self.instance.user.profile`.

Comment: You should really reconsider your design. the Manager model is very un-necessary. you already know if a user is a manager or not. and profile user field should be called user not profile to avoid issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the related `Profile` of a `User` with:

```
myuser.profile
```

indeed, a `OneToOneField` is in essence a `ForeignKey` with a `unique=True` constraint. This means that for a `User` there is *at most* one related `Profile`. The [**`related_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name) by default is the name of the class (here `Profile`) in lowercase (so `profile`). You can thus access the related `Profile` with `.profile`. It will raise an `AttributeError` in case no such `Profile` exists.

The modeling of manager however has redundant data: you do not need to specify both the `User` and the `Profile`, you can determine the other by the first. By introducing *duplicate data*, you make it possible that in the future `Manager`s exist where the `user` is updated, but the `user_profile` is not and vice versa. If you need the `profile` and you store the `user`, you can access it with `mymanager.user.profile`, and if you store the `user_profile`, you can access it with `mymanager.user_profile.user`. Storing both thus makes not much sense.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

Comment: I tried
 self.fields['user_profile'].queryset = self.instance.user.profile 
but still got an AttributeError, ' 'Profile' object has no attribute 'all'' (not sure where 'all' is coming from here).
And thanks for letting me know where to improve on the db, appreciate it!

Comment: i tried tracing back......
a = self.instance.user.profile  gave me the correct user profile but, when i did self.fields['user_profile'].queryset = a  gave me the "AttributeError", with ' 'Profile' object has no attribute 'all''

Comment: @Kim: you should not use `.all()`, `.profile` is a *single* `Profile` object.

Comment: yeah, i didn't. I used self.fields['user_profile'].queryset = self.instance.user.profile But weirdly enough i keep getting AttributeError, ' 'Profile' object has no attribute 'all''.

Comment: @Kim: that's because you assign it to the queryset of a form field, but it makes no sense to specify a form field: there is only one option: the *profile of the* selected user.